# Parsing array of chars into ***char

Tags: c, arrays, shell, parsing, char

I've a array of chars as a result of `gets()` (which is a command inputed to my shell), for example "ls -l \ | sort". Now what I want to have is a char*** that would hold pointers to particular commands (so split by |). With my example:

```
*1[] = {"ls", "-l", "\", null}
*2[] = {"sort", null}
```

and my char*** would be `{1,2}`. The thing is, I don't know how many strings will be given to me in this array of characters, so I can't predefine that. What I have now is just splitting the array of chars into words by whitespaces and I can't figure out how to do what I actually need.

Also in my input/output above the function should react the same to "ls -l \|sort" and "ls -l \ | sort"

My code so far:

```
int parse(char *line, char **argv)
{
    while (*line != '\0') {     
        while (*line == ' ' || *line == '\t' || *line == '\n')
            *line++ = '\0'; 
        *argv++ = line;     
        while (*line != '\0' && *line != ' ' && *line != '\t' && *line != '\n'){
            line++;
        }
    }
    *argv = '\0';  
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve. How do you read from stdin ?

Comment: With gets() into char line[1024] and then this line variable gets passed to parse(char *line, char **argv), where argv is empty and ready to be filled by this function.

Comment: You want to split a string into an array of words ?

Comment: Not exactly - I want to have n+1 arrays of words for n "|" characters. So "ls -l \ | sort" would produce 2 arrays, one with {"ls", "-l", "\", null} and second with {"sort", null}

Answer (score 0):

To split a line, use `strtok()`. You can use this function with `|` as delimiter and then with :

```
#include <string.h>

int parse(char *line, char **argv, const char *delim)
{
    int word_counter = 0
    /* get the first word */
    char *word = strtok(line, delim);

    /* walk through other words */
    while (word != NULL) 
    {
       printf(" %s\n", word);
       word_counter++; 

       /* save word somewhere */

       word = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }

    printf("This string contains %d words separated with %s\n",word_counter,delim);
}
```